# Explicit consent for Facebook autoposting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently, I have a project that users can play a mini-game on a website.

After playing the game, there is a form that required the users to fill-in with the button "submit and share to Facebook".

The logic behind the button is that, it will save the form data to database and check if the user grant the permission Publish Action, if so, it will do the posting action to the user's Facebook timeline.

The reason we did not use Feed or Share dialog is that our clients worry that the users will share some improper content, we will need to track the post ID and delete it if necessary.

Today the Facebook app is being restricted as it violated the Facebook Platform Policies.

I wonder the button "submit and share to Facebook" does not mean obtain their permission each time?? If so, how should I change the flow to fit the Facebook policy?

Thanks in advance

> Your app appears to be posting without explicit consent and creating a
>   negative experience on Facebook. As a reminder, when a person grants
>   your app write permissions this is a technical grant enabling your app
>   to create custom share options. After people grant your app a write
>   permission, you must still obtain their permission each time your app
>   allows them to share to Facebook. In order for us to consider your
>   appeal, your app will need to stop autoposting. Below you'll find
>   information related to the app you want to appeal. Please describe
>   what your app does and how it distributes content via Facebook Social
>   Channels in the 'Appeal Message' section to help us evaluate your
>   appeal.

Comment: what would "improper content" be? why is that so important? i mean, it´s the user who posts it, why do you care? and what are you posting? are you maybe prefilling the message?

Comment: no there are no any prefilling message. we will ask the user to upload a photo then we will generate a gif and share it to their facebook. the client worried the users' would upload some improper photo and ruin their brand

Comment: do you show the user what exactly you will post, before he can approve it?

Comment: Do u mean just like a feed dialogue ?

Comment: no, like...show him what you will post in your own ui. how else would the user know what gets posted on his wall? you should never post something without showing the user EXACTLY what will get posted.

Comment: Oh ... I may understand what u mean now.. And do u have any live example of this?

Comment: a live example? i am not sure what you expect, i don´t know how your app looks like. just present the user what will get posted, that´s all.